# Parse input and export to Excel file using specified format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportingservices-2005

I was asked to produce an Excel file of a specific format, using text as input. User will input text into a TextBox in asp.net, which I will parse/process and export to Excel.

Since the Excel file format is specified, I am thinking of using Reporting Services 2005 and vb.net.
I am open to any other suggestion though, provided that vb.net will be used.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have tried to parse the text given to make it xml.

Comment: if you are happy with xml spreadsheet (.xlsx), try OpenXML, google it and you will find tons of samples online

Comment: I thought of converting the text to xml (file or text) and then pass it dynamically as Datasource to the report. And this is where I can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use reporting tools for this? If I understand your problem correctly, you can very easily using this link

[Using VB.NET to write to excel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cab76ead-2166-4394-8a4b-5b1d0cf5c826/open-and-write-to-an-excel-file-from-vbnet-form)

Comment: Users need a report that can be exported to Excel.